# DTD Validation #Required Field and empty string

Tags: c#, xml, dtd, required

I'm doing XML validation in our system, and I've already achieved this thru XmlReader, But I want to validate a #Required Attribute with EMPTY STRING value. Is there a way to achieve this in DTD Attribute?

DTD:

```
<!ATTLIST TEST
   pUsername CDATA #REQUIRED (...SHOULD NOT BE AN EMPTY STRING)
   pTestAttrib CDATA #REQUIRED (...SHOULD NOT BE AN EMPTY STRING)
   >
```

XML:

```
<TEST pUsername="" pTestAttrib=""> (I want to validate if this attribute value is empty string)
```

C#: Pseudo code

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationEventHandler += delegate (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) { messageBuilder.AppendLine(args.Message); };
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
{
    do
    {
    }
    while (reader.Read());
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? I don't understand, what do you want to do

Comment: @Backs already edited my question, sorry for that, that was my first question..

Comment: You added [c#] tag, but I don't see any code. You want us to write whole solution for you? You should try yourself first, and if you have problems in your code, you can ask here.

Comment: already edited.. thank you for correction by the way..

Comment: Do you know what kinds of values are going to be in those attributes? Maybe you can declare them as [NMTOKEN or NMTOKENS](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken) instead of CDATA. Otherwise you're stuck as far as DTD changes go.

Comment: No, the values came from 3rd party system (via API), so the value would be random. NMTOKENS works for me, I just changed it from CDATA to NMTOKENS  <!ATTLIST TEST
   pUsername NMTOKENS #REQUIRED 
   pTestAttrib NMTOKENS #REQUIRED   > Thank you @DanielHaley i dont know how to +ur comment or mark as answer

Comment: I added an answer that you can accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the attributes as [NMTOKEN or NMTOKENS](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken), but the values for those attributes will need to only consist of [`NameChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar)'s.

Not sure if that will work for all possible values coming from the 3rd party system or not.

If not, you're stuck as far as DTD changes go.

Comment: yeah, that's my new problem now if value consists any nt-namechar i got validation error. I can validate the passed value thru my business object but I want it as simple as possible. so yeah I'm stuck in dtd now.